# Running Adblock Plus webextention on chrome --headless

Tags: google-chrome, headless-browser, adblock

Chrome version : 58 
OS : Ubuntu 16.04

I wanted to take screenshot after blocking ads in chrome --headless mode.For which I have added an entry in default_apps/external_extensions.json for property external_update_url. (Ref : [Link](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/how-the-extension-system-works/default-apps))

When I run the application with
`google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu`

I am able to see that the adblock plugin is active and blocking adds,While when I tried to run
`google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu`

(i.e in headless mode) the adblock plugin is not running or enabled.

I verified the fact by taking screenshot of viewport in both modes. Can anyone please help me to run the adblock plus extension for headless mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run Google Chrome in headless mode with extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372066/is-it-possible-to-run-google-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

Headless Chrome does not support extensions, but you can render Chrome on a virtual display. See [Is it possible to run Google Chrome in headless mode with extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372066/is-it-possible-to-run-google-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-extensions/45372648#45372648)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20026443)

Comment: @digital.aaron I disagree, the answer is _"Headless Chrome does not support extensions"_, the rest is just hinting towards an alternative.