# Is it possible to run Google Chrome in headless mode with extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-headless

I cannot use my currently installed extensions in Google Chrome using headless mode. Is there any way to enable them?

An easy way to check if the extensions work is by adding, for example, the "[Comic Sans Everything](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/comic-sans-everything/oaehjhfpohkdjkpcdbblepomnflojfli?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)" extension.

So Google looks like that:

[image: Google looks beautiful]

However, if I take a screenshot of the page using the headless mode (`google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.google.com`), the result is:

[image: Google in headless mode]

Comment: Not possible currently, see https://crbug.com/706008

Comment: Related: [Using Google Chrome's Puppeteer to load an extension](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/659) - though it won't work headless.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer is no longer correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73079789/934239

No, it's not possible, and Chrome developers [decided against implementing it in any near future](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5) due to complexity of the task.

If you look at that issue you may get the idea that they are still considering it due to ChromeDriver requirements - but instead they decided to make ChromeDriver work without extensions (through DevTools).

Comment: will headless mode support extension in the future? are there any other web browser that support headless mode with extensions?

Comment: Yes firefox supports them. This is a crappy missing feature.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore: ``--headless=chrome`` was added in 2021 as a way of running Chrome in headless mode without loss of features. See the comment here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

Comment: @MichaelMintz I invite you to make a new answer, would gladly upvote it.

Comment: That newer answer has already been added by someone else.

Comment: have a try "--haedless=new" for chrome version > 109  :)

Answer (score 47):

You can run Chrome with extensions headless using [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

1. Install Xvfb. On Fedora `sudo dnf install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`
2. `xvfb-run google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu  https://www.google.com`
3. Use [chrome-remote-interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-remote-interface) (or another Chrome Debug Protocol client) to trigger the screenshot.

More complicated, but it does work. It's what we use for headless chrome extension testing.

Comment: Just to clarify: this solution does not use Chrome's built-in "headless" mode, but instead renders Chrome on a virtual display.

Comment: Thank you. `xvfb-run` also works with Selenium without remote debugging options, for example: `xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1920x1080x24" python run-selenium.py`. See [How To Run Your Tests Headlessly with Xvfb](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless)

Answer (score 20):

Due to recent changes in headless mode, if you are having problems, you might need to use `--headless=new` instead of `--headless=chrome`

```
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

edit:
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

Comment: THANKS! How did you get that info?

Comment: @manuell I dug around and found this bug issue
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1380881
Now it is added to selenium website too
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

Comment: thanks!    "--headless=new" works here

Answer (score 16):

You can use `pyvirtualdisplay` to run the chrome with zero display on your server. The best thing is you can run extensions by using this trick.

Here is my implementation:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_extension("proxy.zip")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', 
    chrome_options=chrome_options
)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get("https://ipinfo.io/json")
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()

display.stop()
```

You need to install `xvfb` on your server/machine:

```
sudo apt install -y xvfb
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

Running it on my AWS Server

[image: aws server]

Comment: Just to know, did you use the flags `--headless --no-sandbox`?

Answer (score 15):

Actually it works now, they fixed it.
You can use

```python
options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

Works like a charm.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

Comment: this might be a dumb question, but what's `options` here and how do I use this code snippet to run headless chrome?

Comment: @Jin The answer is in python (see john's answer codes above). There 'options' is a variable that stores command line arguments that will be passed when launching any application via command line, in this case the application would be chrome.

Answer (score 3):

options.add_argument("--headless=chrome") works

Comment: Yet it doesn't behave in the same way. On mac, `--headless=chrome` still creates a chrome instance that shows in the app switched (command-tab), whereas `--headless` does not. If this is different, what else is?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried it and it works well!

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

Comment: I agree, this is the new correct answer. For more information: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/#what-are-the-two-headless-modes

Answer (score 2):

**No**, [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) in [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) mode doesn't supports extensions yet.

`skyos...@chromium.org` in his [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5) clearly mentioned:

> We've decided against implementing extension support in headless mode for now because supporting all the required features is rather complex

You can find the complete analysis in [Add extension support for headless chrome](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OeUik1MZb1qSQ_Dnf1kIYcyCgLYRZHg1GlZo06bsKx4/edit#heading=h.o067l9gdl1jy)

`eseckler@chromium.org` in his [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c28) mentioned the real time issues as:

1. A lot of extension APIs are specific to non-headless browsers, so can't be supported in headless chrome.
2. Of the APIs we could feasibly support, only parts are implemented in such a way that we can currently reuse them for headless chrome.
3. Changing this requires a lot of refactoring that doesn't seem justified given the benefit we'd gain.

He further added,

> Either way, extensions would likely have to be adapted to work with headless chrome due to (1). So even if we solved (2), most existing extensions would not be compatible. (This also renders headless chrome unsuitable for testing chrome extensions.)
>
> Most if not all functions that extensions could provide to headless chrome can be realized via the DevTools API that headless exposes to its users. If you have a use case that isn't supported via the DevTools API, please file a feature request.

Moreover, in his [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324#c57), `alexclarke@chromium.org` clearly mentioned:

> I realize a lot of folks would like to use extensions with headless but unfortunately that's a large project which we have /no plans to do/.  The problem is Headless Chromium is a content embedder which means it doesn't have access to anything from other content embedders such as chrome and unfortunately extensions are a chrome feature.

In another [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324#c54) he further added, if you're using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) through [DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59420493/how-to-use-chrome-devtools-protocol-in-selenium-using-python-for-capturing-htt/59424003#59424003) you can build a proxy. You can filter URLs and modify headers via [Network.setRequestInterception](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setRequestInterception)  and [Network.continueInterceptedRequest](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-continueInterceptedRequest).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but look at this

https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/2ed6645812603b20a7a249d4a66e286eb407300c/lib/Chrome/ChromeOptions.php#L83

phpdoc reads

```
/**
     * Add a Chrome extension to install on browser startup. Each path should be
     * a packed Chrome extension.
     *
     * @param array $paths
     * @return ChromeOptions
     */
    public function addExtensions(array $paths)
```

Answer (score 0):

If options.add_argument("--headless=chrome") doesn't work for you, you can use pyvirtualdisplay. First install pyvirtualdisplay with pip and on Linux machine run `apt-get install xvfb`.
You can find here how to use pyvirtualdisplay https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay

And you need to remove --headless argument from ChromeOptions.