# Hide browser in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I need to keep a browser running in the background for a specific issue but i have to hide it so the enduser should not see. I have tried electron, nwjs and carlo and ended up using puppeteer since none of the above was meeting my expectation. I need to run a specific chrome extension. I have completed everything but i can't find out how to hide the chronium. I have tried "--no-startup-window" argument for chromium and window doesn't show up but code get stuck at

```
await puppeteer.launch(options);
```

I have read through puppeteer api and look through chronium args but could not figure out. Is there a way to hide chronium but run it in the background?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably would like to run Chromium in headless mode. For this you may use command line switch or `launch` options. More information on [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) is available at this article.

Starting headless:

```
chrome --headless
```

Using `puppeteer` launch options:

```
{
    "headless": true,
    "args": ["--fast-start", "--disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox"],
    "ignoreHTTPSErrors": true
}
```

Comment: I can't run chrome in headless mode cause i want to load an extension. You can't load extensions in headless mode. "--disable-extensions" not working for me.

Comment: @KaanBoz In this case this is duplicate of [Is it possible to run Google Chrome in headless mode with extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372066/is-it-possible-to-run-google-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-extensions/45372648#45372648)

Comment: It is a similiar issue but they want to run chrome in headless mode, i don't care about headless mode, i just want to hide it so the end user wont see. But i think it is not possible. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Is it possible to run in headful mode but keep browser minimized? Since the browser keeps jumping foreground, which hinders me from doing other things on my computer.

Comment: @avocado I am not sure. We never need it, so I never question myself. Would you mind to post this as the new question, somebody will help. Thanks.