# application is not able to record sound while the selenium script runs in headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web app that records sound when the user presses a button. I created a selenium script that clicks on the element to record the sound. It works perfectly except in headless mode. The script log shows that the element was pressed but the result is an empty sound file.

Is there a chromedriver option that would allow for it to record sound while in headless mode? I am thinking that the mic is not picking up sound or gets muted(?). This is probably a very limited use case. I searched quite a bit but could not find anybody with similar issues.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Google Chrome in headless mode with extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372066/is-it-possible-to-run-google-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-extensions)

Comment: Thank you SiKing. I am going to use the screenshot implementation mentioned there to see if something else is going on. I am not sure that the mic feature qualifies as an extension but will investigate