# Is it possible to have headless mode, and a browser extension? in Selenium with python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been working on a personal project, and I find myself unable to work with both headless, and utilize a browser extension at the same time. I can only choose one or the other.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

ghostery = "D:\\Coding\\python\\web\\WebPlayer\\ghostery.crx"
opts = Options()
opts.add_extension(ghostery)
opts.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
```

This is what I currently have. Commenting either the `opts.add_extension()` line or `opts.add_argument()` line will make it work perfectly. But I want to be able to use both features at the same time. I have tried alternatives such as:

```
# same imports as above
ghostery = "D:\\Coding\\python\\web\\WebPlayer\\ghostery.crx"
opts = Options()
opts.add_extension(ghostery)
opts.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
```

This does not work. I have had other alternatives as well, but they all don't work for the same reasons as mentioned above.

Edit:
I decided to use Firefox instead which fixed the issue. I can now use headless and addons at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Google Chrome in headless mode with extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372066/is-it-possible-to-run-google-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-extensions)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But no, I've seen this before, and tried to use the given solution. But it didn't work.