# Why is it not possible to load extension in Cypress using headless mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cypress, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I've developed a chrome extension and I would like to e2e test it in a pipeline. So I install Cypress. But then I saw the following code example

[image]

> // NOTE: extensions cannot be loaded in headless Chrome

It states that it is not possible to load an extension in headless mode. Why is this the case, I assume that there is a good reason for this.

[SOURCE](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Set-screen-size-when-running-headless)

Comment: This is a Chrome restriction, and not unique to Cypress. [More info in this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62347398/11625850)